# Get definite City name in Google maps reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps Geocoding API, i'm able to get the formatted address for a particular coordinate. To get the exact city name, I'm doing the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+long+'&sensor=false',
    success: function(data){
        var formatted = data.results;
        var address_array = formatted[6].formatted_address.split(',');
        var city = address_array[0];
   }
});
```

where `lat` and `long` are derived using the browser coordinates. My problem is the following:

From coordinates `19.2100` and `72.1800`, I get the city as `Mumbai`, but from a similar set of coordinates about 3Km away, I get city as `Mumbai Suburban`. How can I get `Mumbai` without changing the success function of my code? It seems to me that the result array doesn't always stick to the same format which creates problems in my displaying of the city name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the type of the result, not the absolute index in the array of results.  Iterate through the results array looking for the entry which has the appropriate [type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types).  Looks like that would be:

- locality indicates an incorporated city or town political entity

But data may vary with region.

related question: [Grabbing country from google geocode jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937879/grabbing-country-from-google-geocode-jquery/16942609#16942609)

Looks like you want the entry with both the 'locality' and the 'political' types:

```
{
   "long_name" : "Mumbai",
   "short_name" : "Mumbai",
   "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So I was trying to figure this out today and I came to this solution if it helps anyone.  Google maps comes with the Geocoder built in now so you just create a geocoder object once the API has loaded.

You can easily wrap that in a function and just return an object with the city, state, and postal code.  This site was helpful in allowing me to see what the different 'types' mean:  [Reverse Geocoding](http://noc.to/geodecode#28.5400000,-81.3900000)

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder,
    latitude = 28.54, //sub in your latitude
    longitude = -81.39, //sub in your longitude
    postal_code,
    city,
    state;
geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:latitude, lng:longitude}}, function(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    results.forEach(function(element){
      element.address_components.forEach(function(element2){
        element2.types.forEach(function(element3){
          switch(element3){
            case 'postal_code':
              postal_code = element2.long_name;
              break;
            case 'administrative_area_level_1':
              state = element2.long_name;
              break;
            case 'locality':
              city = element2.long_name;
              break;
          }
        })
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brett :) Worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I was looking for something similar and am trying https://plus.codes/

If you strip the encoded bit it yields a fairly consistent city, state, country name:

```
const extractCityName = latlng => {
  googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({ latlng }, (err, response) => {
    if (!err) {
      return response.json.plus_code.compound_code.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    }
  });
};


// examples: 

console.log(extractCityName(40.6599718,-73.9817292));
// New York, NY, USA

console.log(extractCityName(37.386052, -122.083851));
// Mountain View, CA, USA

console.log(extractCityName(51.507351, -0.127758));
// Westminster, London, UK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get({
            url: locAPI,
            success: function(data)
            {
                data.results[0].address_components.forEach(function(element){
                    // console.log(element.types);
                    if(element.types[0] == 'locality' && element.types[1] == 'political')
                    {
                        console.log('City:')
                        console.log(element.long_name);
                    }
                    if(element.types[0] == 'country' && element.types[1] == 'political')
                    {
                        console.log('Country:')
                        console.log(element.long_name);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

In My Case, I had to find City and Country Name.. That's what I did.