# Check if coordinates lie in a region

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, bing-maps

If I have a (latitude,longitude) pair, is there a way to determine whether it lies in a 'region'. By region I mean the 'highlighted' result of an query in google maps. For example, when I search for Manhattan, a red region is highlighted. Does Google/Bing provide an API to query if a given coordinate lie in such a region? 
I am aware of the containsLocation API call that tells me if a coordinate lies in a polynomial already defined as a set of coordinates. The problem here is me not having all the coordinates that can define Delhi

Comment: One option would be to reverse geocode the point; look to see if it contains that region.  Related question [Get definite City name in Google maps reverse geocoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524422/get-definite-city-name-in-google-maps-reverse-geocoding/)

Comment: People who recommend a question for closing, please care to explain yourself. It's called being polite. I'm asking for a question related to programming. I don't see how the question is 'bad'?

Comment: I'm resorting to Ctrl-Clicking the boundaries of the region to get a set of coordinates, I will then create a polygon using maps api and thereafter use containsLocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps provides an API called the GeoData API where you can pass in a coordinate and it will return the boundary information for the intersecting location (city in this case). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306801.aspx

Another method as mentioned by others in the comments is to use a reverse geocoding service. By passing in your coordinates it will return the name of the city in which that coordinate is in. Bing Maps also has a Reverse Geocoding service:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx